# MWFeedParser tag inside tag (media:thumbnail)

Tags: iphone, xml, rss, youtube, feedparser

i am using MWFeedParser to read from Youtube atom feed from here: [here](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/FPSRussia/uploads?alt=rss)

Xml code:

```
 <media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/7_1PfqGVSg0/0.jpg' height='240' width='320' time='00:01:34.500'/>
```

how i can get the url of media:thumbnail?
i tried to change in MWFeedParser.m
from this:

```
else if ([currentPath isEqualToString:@"/feed/entry/link"]) { [self processAtomLink:currentElementAttributes andAddToMWObject:item]; processed = YES; }
```

to this:

```
else if ([currentPath isEqualToString:@"/feed/entry/media:thumbnail"]) { [self processAtomLink:currentElementAttributes andAddToMWObject:item]; processed = YES; }
```

but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the section case FeedTypeAtom add the following code:

```
else if ([currentPath isEqualToString:@"/feed/entry/media:group/media:thumbnail"]) {
    NSString *urlString = [currentElementAttributes objectForKey:@"url"];                   
    if ( urlString != nil && urlString.length > 0) 
        item.thumbnail = urlString;  
    processed = YES;
}
```

Also add NSString *thumbnail properties to the MWFeedItem object